# collectstatic command excluding nested directories and files

Tags: django

I'm trying to exclude some of the files and directories from static folder for `collectstatic` command.

```
static
  -sample
  -css
     -dest
     -vendor 
     index.css
```

I want to exclude the `vendor` directory and file `index.css`.

Tried following:

`python manage.py collectstatic -i css/vendor -i css/*.css -i sample`

It excluded the `sample` but not `vendor` directory and file `index.css`.

What could be the possible solution for this ?

Comment: Django collectstatic ignoring mechanism is based on [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) library, I suggest trying experimenting with it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that. because currently django `collectstatic` management command, doesn't support ignoring path. you can just use name of folders and pass it as as `--ignore` input.

So in your case `collectstatic` can ignore the folder with name `sample`, but others are path and can't be ignored. (I know it's not a good answer to hear, but that's what it is currently on django)